# Apple Push Notifications, how do I properly export my cert?

Tags: iphone, certificate, openssl, push

I can't seem to figure out how to properly export my cert for use in my iOS app with push notifications. I'm using the following cert, downloaded from the **Certificates** section of the **iOS Provisioning Portal**.

[image]

I'm then following one of the many tutorials I've found all over the web that are all different by the way, to get my cert into a **.pem** format for use in **[ruby-apns](http://code.google.com/p/ruby-apns-daemon/)**.

First I export it from the Keychain:

[image]

After I give it a name and a password I perform the following commands in the terminal*:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out apple_push_notification_dev.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

**note: this isn't the only way I've tried this, just the latest, I have also tried via the instructions at the following urls:*

- http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/06/05/how-to-renew-your-apple-push-notification-push-ssl-certificate/
- http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/
- http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/wiki/HowToCreatePKCS12Certificate
- http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Apple_Push_Notification_Service

Not a single one of these solutions work. I'm sitting here looking at the following error from the console when I try to use ruby-apns:

```
read finished A: sslv3 alert certificate unknown (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

And essentially every other server solution I've found has told me my certificate is incorrect or that there's a problem with it as well.

Am I doing this wrong?

===============================

### Overnight Courtesy Bump Stealth Edit

So I beat my head against the wall last night, and actually came across Apple's own instructions for doing this. It's almost the exact same, and I tried it to the same tune. Nevertheless, here is the latest attempt from [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1):

```
openssl pkcs12 -in CertificateName.p12 -out CertificateName.pem -nodes
```

Comment: Not an answer but a recommendation. Try to create a new developer-certificate for that app. Ruby experts might also find useful to know your ruby version.

Comment: Please check all the steps I mentioned below and let me know if you have any questions or still you are not able create the .pem file there.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

(1) First you need to set the configuration for your app ID to enable push notification service. You can check in the image.
[image]

(2) Then You can install the certificate and intall in your keychain in your machine.
[image]

(3) Here you are exporting two files. Instead of that you just need to export the private key as shown in the screenshot.
[image]

(4) Now you can export the private key and store with any name you want in .p12 format as shown in the screenshot below.
[image]

(5) Then follows all other steps as you know very well like you mentioned above.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in CertificateName.p12 -out CertificateName.pem -nodes
```

Please let me know if you still have any question or if you are not able to solve then let me know.

Comment: I also see it weird, UrbanAirship doesn't work if you just export one. But I am having the same problem I will test with one :)