# How to connect to APNS for updating a pass

Tags: web-services, ios6, apple-push-notifications, passbook

I am doing server for updating a pass. Now I want to send notification to APNS, but it doesn't work. This is errors from php_error.log:  `[10-Apr-2013 08:59:24 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file` `` `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/certificatePass.pem' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/pushNotification.php on line 32 `` 
`[10-Apr-2013 08:59:24 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): failed to create an SSL handle in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/pushNotification.php on line 32` 
 
`[10-Apr-2013 08:59:24 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/pushNotification.php on line 32`
`[10-Apr-2013 08:59:24 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/pushNotification.php on line 32`

//line 32: $tSocket = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $tHost . ':' . $tPort, $error, $error_string, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $tContext);

Comment: Looks like your server cannot find or maybe cannot access /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/certificatePass.pem - check that the file exists and that your web server has permission to access it.

Comment: I export certificatePass.pem from pass.cer. Do I need to use other certificates ?

Comment: I check permission already, but I still get same problems. These are some of my codes for getting the certificate: $tCert = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/certificatePass.pem';
stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $tCert);

Comment: $tPassphrase = "";

$query = mysql_query("select * from devices");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
     
$tToken = $row['pushToken'];

$payload = json_encode ("");

// Create the Socket Stream.
$tContext = stream_context_create ();
stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $tCert);

// Remove this line if you would like to enter the Private Key Passphrase manually.
stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $tPassphrase);

Comment: Do I use $deviceID or $pushToken to send to APNS ?

Comment: You use the pushToken. What is in your .pem file? (Don't paste all of it just the first 2 lines?)

Comment: where do I put the code for connecting APNS ? (after registering device or .... ?)

Comment: I just export pass.cer to certificatePass.pem. To create pass, I use only passTypeID certificate and sign from companion file by using command: ./sign -p Pass_name; I don't have any key !

Comment: The first 2 lines ? Then, What I have to do is to connect send pushToken to APNS, right ?

Comment: What do you mean export pass.cer to certificatePass.pem? You need the pass type ID private and public key pair to connect.  How are you exporting these?

Comment: I use this command :   openssl x509 -inform der -in pass.cer -out certificatePass.pem

Comment: And what about the key? This post gives a useful guide as to how to export the key and certificate and convert the .p12 key into one you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576660/apple-push-notifications-how-do-i-properly-export-my-cert

Comment: Thank you! and I have to export my pass Type ID, not iphone distribution , right ?

Comment: yes, I see my key now !

Comment: Yes - the private key for the Pass Type ID certificate is the one you want.

Comment: So I don't use aps_development.cer and aps_production.cer ?

Comment: Don't user aps_developement or aps_production - go into your Keychain and export the Key `Pass Type ID: pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest`.  Thinking about it, you should have already done this because you needed the certificate to sign the pass in the first place.

Comment: So I need to use only cert.12 that I export from pass Type ID ?

Comment: I have to use only cert.pem to connect to APNs ?

Comment: how can I use key.pem ?

Comment: Open a text editor and paste the contents of key.pem and cert.pem into a single file.  If you did not set a password when you converted the key from .p12 to pem with openssl, then  use `stream_context_set_option($tContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/path/to/combined/cert/and/key/file.pem');`. If you set a password, then add `stream_context_set_option($tContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'yourPassword');`

Comment: Do I have to use array or not for pushToken :  $pushToken = array($row1['pushToken']);
 ?

Comment: I don't use array and now there is no problem, but I see any message in php_error.log !

Comment: There may be no error because your script could be working OK.  You should be looking at your device in the Xcode console when you send the push.  If it is working you will see the device receive the push and then start calling your webservice.

Comment: when I comment condition, now errors appear like before !

Comment: in console: Apr 11 12:33:59 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[4987] <Warning>: BOM could not extract archive: Couldn't read PKZip signature

Comment: now connection is OK, but I not yet send pushToken to APNs yet ? how to send pushToken ?

Comment: I use :   $ConnectAPNS = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

Comment: what is number 60 means ?

Comment: Do I send to apns like this : foreach($pushToken as $device_token){
   $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device_token)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
  }

Comment: See code below - also note that you should be connecting to the live APNS server, not the sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code you have provided in the comments, try:

```
$tToken = $row['pushToken']; 
$payload = json_encode (array("aps" => ""));
$tCert = '/path/to/combined/cert/and/key/file.pem';
$tPassword = 'your certificate password'; 

// Create the and config the socket context. 
$tContext = stream_context_create (); 
stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $tCert);
if (strlen($tPassword))
    stream_context_set_option($tContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $tPassword);

// Compose and pack the push message
$apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $tToken)) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Connect and write the push message to the connection
$ConnectAPNS = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
$success = fwrite($ConnectAPNS, $apns_message);

if ($success)
    error_log(date('d-m-Y hh:ii:ss', time()) . ': APNS Message successfully sent to device token' . $tToken, 0);
else
    error_log(date('d-m-Y hh:ii:ss', time()) . ': Push error:' . $err . ': ' . $errstr);
```

Comment: Do you what 60 refers to in this line : $ConnectAPNS = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext); ?

Comment: How to test if this push notification work well for a new updated pass ?

Comment: for getting pass, I use: if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])){
     header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
     exit;
 } else { //get pass

Comment: but I never get new pass and always get response 304 !

Comment: what condition should I put for $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] ?

Comment: `if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) && strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) >= $lastUpdated) { header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified'); exit; } else { //get pass` $lastUpdated can be either from your database, or from filemtime('/path/to/pass.pkpass');

Comment: Thank you PassKit ! I just now don't know if this push works automatically!

Comment: It depends what you mean by automatically.  You should only trigger a push when you have a new .pkpass bundle to deliver.  So automatic could mean that you have a process that whenever you update  the .pkpass, your database updates and sends a push to the device.

Comment: my push notification doesn't work automatically ! But thank PassKit !