# SSL certificates and Rapns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, openssl, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to set up a Rails application using the Rapns library to send push notifications. The project already has this gem configured, I am working toward upgrading it to Rpush. However, I'm having a lot of trouble setting up my certificates.

I've generated all the key pairs and certificates I need with much help from the following articles:

[Apple Push Notifications, how do I properly export my cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576660/apple-push-notifications-how-do-i-properly-export-my-cert)
http://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Running the following command

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert /path/to/my/sandbox.pem -debug -showcerts
```

returns the following

```
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

So with help from [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG31) I downloaded a CA certificate and ran the following

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert /path/to/my/sandbox.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile /path/to/my/entrust_2048_ca.cer
```

and got

```
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Success! However, my call to run the notifying application

```
bundle exec rapns development
```

Outputs 2 lines initially

```
[2014-08-04 14:29:42] [my app ID] Started, 1 handler.
[2014-08-04 14:29:43] [my app ID] Connected to feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196
```

but then does nothing as I attempt to trigger notifications. *Additionally* it will re-prompt me for my PEM pass phrase periodically, making me think it's not really authenticating (which may be a symptom of the `return code 20` from before).

I didn't actually fix the certificate itself (I don't think) by downloading the CA certificate. How do I incorporate that into the PEM so this works, or otherwise configure Rapns such that I don't need the CA cert?

Comment: *"it will re-prompt me for my PEM pass phrase periodically..."* - you can remove the password with the `-nodes` option. That should remove the prompt in case that's mucking up the machinery. Just read the key or certificate in and write it back out while including `-nodes`.